# Is there a lower bound for the nth primorial?

Tags: primorial

Can $n\#$ (product of all primes less or equal to n) be bounded from below by some lower bound such as $2^n$?

Comment: though it seems from [OEIS A034386](https://oeis.org/A034386) that $2.76279^n$ and more simply $3^n$ should be upper bounds

Answer (score 2):

[OEIS A002110](https://oeis.org/A002110) (it would be more appropriate if it were A002310) lists the primorials but indexes them in order, not by the highest prime.  It says that the values are $\left( m^m\right)^{1+o(1)}$.  We can use the fact that the prime counting function is a little greater than $\frac n{\log n}$ to say that $n\# \gt \left(\frac n{\log n}\right)^{\frac n{\log n}}$ for $n$ prime